# Flagging closed questions for deletion

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, flagging

I've flagged two questions recently:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7491/c-how-to-take-file-ownership-to-the-current-user-using-win32-api
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/16100/what-am-i-doing-wrong-sql-connection-in-vb-net

Both are closed without any answer and it does not seem that they help anyone, so I think we can delete them. The [moderator tools help page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) also says the following:

> When should I delete questions?
>
> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted.

Both flag was declined with the following reason:

> "declined - flags should only be used to make
>   moderators aware of content that requires their intervention "

I'm just wondering - is there any reason to keep these question? Should I flag this kind of questions in the future? (I've also vote for deletion but it does not seem that they will get three delete votes in the near future unless I write this question on the Meta CR... :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My bad. I should have deleted those questions.

You were the first to ever suggest the deletion of these questions and my initial reaction was not to as we've never done it before.

I've deleted those questions now.

Comment: I know this is an old discussion, but there's no sense in me creating a new question about this.  Should any incoming closed *and* worthless question get deleted (hopefully by the community)?  I'm not sure how SO does it, and I can't help but feel that we shouldn't get delete-happy.  Or maybe this is just what we need to do.